# CSS property box-shadow not working with the white color

Tags: css

Here is the css class I am applying to my image tag on mouse hover:

```
div#simpleSearch button#searchButton > img:hover {
    /* Box-shadow */
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px #AFAFAF; 
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px #AFAFAF;

    /* Border-Radius */
-moz-border-radius: 100px; /* Firefox */
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
     border-radius: 100px; /* CSS3 */
}
```

It is working fine. 
But if I replace `#AFAFAF` with either `white` or `#FFFFFF`, no border is applied to my image. I should add that the site background is grey, so a white shadow would be visible.

As anyone already experienced this ? 
Any workaround suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: `-o-border-radius` does not exist. Anyway, can we see a jsFiddle test case?

Comment: ... http://jsfiddle.net/fHsxT/7/ 
It works fine there.

Comment: Thanks for the `o-border-radius`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
-moz-box-shadow: 13px 13px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 13px 13px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
 box-shadow: 13px 13px 0px 0px  #FFFFFF;
```

the last 2 values are optional [as seen here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)

Comment: Always put the unprefixed version last.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can come up with a solution like this if you need to add some white top and bottom `box-shadow` on a `div` element for example :

```
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 60px 50px -30px #ffffff, inset 0px -60px 50px -30px #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Don't forget to add the **z-index**.

Answer (score -1):

I did quick jsfiddle but simplifying the css to just use an ID and it's working fine, it shows the white color when hover.

make sure that your css is really applied to your content

http://jsfiddle.net/fc9dJ/17/